# Method always returning 0

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call a method (ChooseDecoration) using the (DisplayMessage) method and  that will return a value of either 1,2 or something else but right now the method just returns 0 everytime as far as I can tell.

I have tried various ways like getting the decoration value inside the DisplayMessage method but the program specs require a separate method to find these.

```
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
public class ChristmasCard : ChristmasCardTesting
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ToAndFrom();
        double decorate = ChooseDecoration();

        DisplayMessage(decorate);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ToAndFrom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter who you are sending the card to");
        string to = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter who it is from");
        string from = Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static void SetBorderCharacter()
    {

    }
     static double ChooseDecoration()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Choose decoration 1 or 2 ");
       double decoration = Convert.ToDouble(Console.Read());
        return decoration;

    }
    public static void DisplayMessage(double decoration)
    {

        if (decoration == 1)
        {
            ChristmasCardTesting.SantaA();
        }
        else if (decoration == 2)
        {

            ChristmasCardTesting.SantaB();
        }
       // else
        //    ChristmasCardTesting.SantaA();

    }
    public static void DoPromt()
    {

    }
    public static void AddMessage()
    {

    }
    public static void ClearMessage()
    {

    }




}

public class ChristmasCardTesting
{

    public static void SantaA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@" ||::|:|| .--------, ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" |:||:|:| |_______ / .-. ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" ||::|:|| .'` ___ `'. \|('v')|/ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \\\/\///: .'` `'. ;____`( )'____ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \====/ './ o o \|~ ^' '^ // ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \\// | ())) . | Season's \ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" || \ `.__.' /| // ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" || _{``-.___.-'\| Greetings \ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" || _.' `-.____.- '`| ___ // ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" ||` __ \ |___/ \_______\ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" .' || (__) \ \| / ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" / `\/ __ vvvvv'\___/ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" | | (__) | ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \___/\ / ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" || | .___. | ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" || | | | ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" ||.-' | '-. ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" || | ) ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" || ----------'---------' ");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
    public static void SantaB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@" ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" .------, ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" .\/. |______| ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" _\_}{_/_ _|_Ll___|_ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" / }{ \ [__________] .\/. ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" '/\' / \ _\_\/_/_ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" () o o () / /\ \ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \ ~~~ . / '/\' ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" _\/ \ '...' / \/_ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \\ {`------'} // ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \\ /`---/',`\\ // ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \/' o | |\ \`// ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" /' | | \/ /\ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" __,. -- ~~ ~| o `\| |~ ~~ -- . __ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" | | ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" \ o / ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" `._ _.' ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" ^~- . - ~^ ");
        Console.WriteLine(@" ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the program, or having it print out what was returned from your `ChooseDecoration` method?

Comment: Place a breakpoint inside your method and step through the code to see what is happening. You may get some ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use caution when using the [`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, since it only reads the next key from the standard input stream, but blocks until the user presses `Enter`. Any additional characters after the first one are then returned by subsequent calls to `Console.Read`.

Take a look at the following example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 or 2: ");
int i = Console.Read(); // Here the user types: 12[Enter]
// The value of 'i' is now 49 (the ASCII value of 1)

// Later we do this:
Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 or 4:");
int j = Console.Read();
// The value of 'j' is now 50 (the ASCII value of 2), and the code keeps running!
// There is no pause to wait for user input, since there was already some in the cache
```

---

**What you should do instead**

There are two more common ways to get input from the user: `Console.ReadLine()`, which returns the entire string the user entered (after they press 'Enter'), or `Console.ReadKey()`, which returns a `ConsoleKeyInfo` representation of the key they pressed.

You can use `ReadLine` with your code exactly the way it is, and that might be best:

```
double decoration = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

But, if you don't want them to have to press 'Enter', you can do the following, which gets the string representation of the next character the user types by calling `ToString()` on the `KeyChar` property of the `ConsoleKeyInfo` object:

```
double decoration = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString());
```

---

**Add some validation**

But what happens if the user enters a string that can't be converted to a double? In that case, `Convert.ToDouble` will throw an exception. To avoid this, we can use `double.TryParse`, which returns `true` if the conversion is successful and sets an `out` parameter to the converted value. Now we can do something like this, to check if the input is valid:

```
double decoration;

if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decoration))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is not a valid double.");
}
```

But we now have to ask them to input it again, right? And if it fails again... well, we need a loop for this:

```
double decoration;

while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decoration))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is not a valid double.");
    Console.Write("Please Choose decoration 1 or 2: ");
}
```

Now it will continue looping until the user enters a valid double.

---

**Make the code reusable**

Ok, great, now we have a way to validate the input, but do we really want to write that loop code every time we need to get a double from the user? A better idea might be to create a method that does it for us, which takes in a string prompt to display to the user, and returns the correct type. We can even add some "bounds" arguments, to enforce the number is between a min and max value:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a strongly typed (double) value from the Console
/// </summary>
/// <param name="prompt">The initial message to display to the user</param>
/// <returns>User input converted to a double</returns>
public static double GetDoubleFromUser(string prompt = "Enter a number: ", 
    double minValue = double.MinValue, double maxValue = double.MaxValue)
{
    double value;

    // Write the prompt text and get input from user
    Console.Write(prompt);

    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)
           || value < minValue || value > maxValue)
    {
        // If input can't be converted to a double, keep trying
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid value!");
        Console.Write(prompt);
    }

    // Return converted input value
    return value;
}
```

Now, with this code, all we need to do is:

```
double decoration = GetDoubleFromUser("Please Choose decoration 1 or 2: ", 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

`Console.Read` returns an `int`, but that isn't the *numeric key* - it is that `char` value, or `-1` for EOF. So: the problem isn't that it is returning zero. The problem is that it is returning the ASCII value of the key. You need to convert. For example:

```
int i = Console.Read();
if(i < 0) return 0;
char c = (char)i;
return (int)(c - '0');
```

Comment: Thanks not quite sure about how this solves it but it did, what is happening in the char c - (char)i; line?

Comment: @SamJohnson look at an ASCII table. The character code for `0` is 48, `1` is 49, `2` is 50, etc. Don't worry, you don't need to remember this -  the point is that they are successive. So: if we read a **character** `2` and want to understand that as the **number** 2: we need to subtract 48. Or more simply: we subtract the *character code* of `0`. You can do the same trick with alphas - so if you want `a` to be 0, `b` to be 1, etc - you do `theChar - 'a'` (note: this is case sensitive)